# Do table permissions carry forward in CREATE TABLE LIKE/AS in Amazon Redshift?

Tags: mysql, analytics, etl, amazon-redshift, create-table

*The description is a bit abstract, but I hope it explains.*

There is a table - table A, with certain permissions to certain users. I need to load data into this table (full load). Rather than truncating the table, I would like a backup so that the data doesn't get lost.

- Rename table A to table B.
- Create table A like table B.
- Load data into table A.
- If data load is successful, apply permissions on table A (in case permissions don't carry when doing a create table X like table Y).
- If data load is unsuccessful, rename table B to table A.
- Apply permissions to table A (if that is needed).

Answer (score 0):

> **When do rename a table A to table B, permissions are carried forward. When you do CREATE TABLE B LIKE TABLE A, then permissions are not carried forward.**